# How to get decoded String from UTF16 encoded String

Tags: c++, c++11, mfc, utf-16

I'm trying to get decoded String from UTF16 encoded String.

Current value of UTF16 is `\u5f00\u53d1\u8005` and original string is `开发者`
In other words,  `\u5f00\u53d1\u8005` `==>` `开发者` using C++`.

How can I do this using C++?

Comment: It's unclear to me, what you are really asking for. If you want to display a UTF-16 encoded character string, the answer depends entirely on where you want to display the string (console, a common control, GDI, Direct2D, etc.). Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I got received UTF16 encoded Byte string from server and I want to show this decoded string "开发者 " from the string in my dialog of MFC.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't help you do that. With that out of the way, how are you planning to display that string? Are you putting it in a control (Edit, ListView, Static, etc.)? Are you rendering it into a device context? Do you want to display it on a Direct2D surface?

Comment: I'm planning to display the string on MessageBox. 
In here, control is not important. 
Things important is to convert UTF16 encoded Byte string to decode string.

Comment: If the byte stream is already UTF-16LE encoded, then all you have to do is cast it to a `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Yeah, How to convert char16_t* to wchat_t*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230105/discussion-between-yong-ju-and-iinspectable).

Comment: You don't need to convert anything. Just cast the type from `char16_t*` to `wchar_t*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have it stored in a `wchar_t` array or `std::string` it's just a matter of correctly setting your environment to deal with wide chars, take this console example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){

  _setmode(fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
  const wchar_t str[] = L"\u5f00\u53d1\u8005";
  //std::wstring str = L"\u5f00\u53d1\u8005";
  std::wcout << str;
    
}
```

It's as simple as that.

To use with `mfc` particularly maybe you should take a look at [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar)  and/or [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte).

There is also [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7958/CTextFileDocument) in Code Project that may have just what you need.

Comment: If I use MFC and my project character setting is MBCS, which function should I use among them and how to set its parameters on current condition("\u5f00\u53d1\u8005")?

Comment: @YongJu, you would want the first, anyway they are quite tricky to use, take a look at that class I linked at the end of the answer, it seems pretty handy for what you are doing, I also found this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/58155934/6865932, take a look there.